# 'Design' view in Android Studio gets "Rendering Problems" and telling me to update Android Studio - but

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to start coding some Android apps, such as a simple Music Player app. I have followed instructions and correctly installed latest Android Studio from vendor site. Also went through countless updates etc and installing SDK and Java 8.

The error message I encounter is when I clicked Design view tab, it says "Rendering Problems" and then tells me that the rendering library I have is more up to date than the Studio and to update to the latest version of Android Studio. When I click Update in AS it says I have latest version 1.2.1.1

I have put a screenshot online:
http://s725.photobucket.com/user/scuntman/media/as_zpsknonswjj.jpg.html?filters[user]=143275810&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Does anybody know how this can be fixed?

Comment: On your screen it says MNC.  Change that to v21.  The next android studio update should have the mobile preview\.

Comment: thanks for the help.. it doesnt let me have v21 but when I untick 'automatically choose best' and then it lets me select API22: Android 5.1.1. ,,,, now the error message is gone but it just an empty grey square and no emulator or anythings whats supposed to be there

Comment: i put image of what I changed it too. hope i done correctly as what you suggested: http://s725.photobucket.com/user/scuntman/media/as_zpsise4vffo.jpg.html

Comment: I would go to the sdk manager and download all the v21 stuff

Comment: then restart android studio

Comment: Android Studio and Inellij both have these problems.

Comment: thank u Eugene. I will do that now. Also, your suggestion did fix the problem but now I get error saying "endering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)"

Comment: I will do the v21 thing and if I still have problems will ask another question. thanks mate

Comment: v22 is stable and the latest, set the project to that and sync your project via `Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files`, this could help. Make sure you don't have any sort of error in your code.

Comment: thanks Razzle, I beleive Eugene was also on the right lines as when I went to SDK Manager many where there still to be downloaded. I am getting them all now and will hopefully find the problem fixed if not i'll start up another question. Thanks again guys!